# RecyclerView not updating when database changes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, sugarorm

I am using **Sugar ORM** to implement Data Persistence in my app. I am displaying my database contents in a **RecyclerView**. The problem is SugarORM doesn't have loaders so there is **no way to refresh the RecyclerView** with fresh data after adding/deleting an entry to the database. I have worked around the issue for phones by reinitializing my Adapter in **OnResume()** and displaying it in the Recycler View. But for Tablets, the logic isn't working because the Fragment **never goes to OnPause**.

**I need to update my the RecyclerView in my FavouritesFragment when I remove an entry in my DetailsFragment**

Here's the Github link https://github.com/Hackertronix/Project-Motion/tree/Stage_2

Here's the code for both fragments

**FavoritesFragment.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views.fragments;

import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Movie;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.API;
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 6/7/2016.
 */
public class FavouritesFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG= "FAVOURITES";
    private static final String FAVOURITE_MOVIES_ARRAY = "favourite_movies";
    private List<Movie> mMovies=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mFavouritesRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<Movie> moviesArrayList;
    private FavouritesAdapter mAdapter;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    public FavouritesFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG,"In OnCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.v(TAG,"OnPause() Called");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
     /*   Sugar ORM does not have a Loader
          so to refresh the recyclerview adapter I am reinitializing it*/

        Log.v(TAG,"OnResume() Called");
        mMovies=Movie.listAll(Movie.class);
        mAdapter=new FavouritesAdapter();
        mFavouritesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mFavouritesRecyclerView.invalidate();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG,"In OnCreateView()");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites,container,false);
        mFavouritesRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.favourites_recyclerview);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null&&savedInstanceState.containsKey(FAVOURITE_MOVIES_ARRAY))
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"Restoring State");
            mMovies=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(FAVOURITE_MOVIES_ARRAY);
        }

        else {
            mMovies=  Movie.listAll(Movie.class);
        }



        if(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

            mFavouritesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new
                    GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        }
        else{
            mFavouritesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        }
        mAdapter= new FavouritesAdapter();
        mFavouritesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mFavouritesRecyclerView.invalidate();
        return view;
    }



    private class FavouritesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        private ImageView mPosterImageView;
        private Movie mMovie;
        public FavouritesHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mPosterImageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bind(Movie movie)
        {
            mMovie=movie;
            Picasso mPicasso= Picasso.with(getActivity());
            mPicasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

            mPicasso.load(API.IMAGE_URL+API.IMAGE_SIZE_500+mMovie.getPosterPath())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .into(mPosterImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ActivityOptions options=ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),mPosterImageView,"posterImage");
            ((openDetailsListener)getActivity()).openDetails(mMovie,options);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        moviesArrayList=new ArrayList<>(mMovies);
        Log.v(TAG,"Saving State");
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(FAVOURITE_MOVIES_ARRAY,moviesArrayList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class FavouritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouritesHolder>
    {


        @Override
        public FavouritesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item,parent,false);
            return new FavouritesHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(FavouritesHolder holder, int position) {

            Movie movie= mMovies.get(position);
            holder.bind(movie);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mMovies.size();
        }
    }
    public interface openDetailsListener{
        void openDetails(Movie movie,ActivityOptions options);
    }
}
```

**DetailsFragment.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views.fragments;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Movie;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Review;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Trailer;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.API;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.JSONParser;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.OkHttpHandler;
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Response;

import static com.execube.genesis.R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp;


/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/30/2016.
 */
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "DETAILS";
    private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_COLORS = 5;

    private Movie mMovie;
    private Movie entry,tempMovie;
    private List<Movie> movie;
    public Intent intent;

    private TextView mDetailTitle;
    private TextView mReleaseDate;
    private TextView mOverview;
    private TextView mOverviewHeader;
    private TextView mReviesHeader;
    private TextView mTrailersHeader;

    private ImageView mBackdrop;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private RatingBar mRatingBar;

    private ArrayList<Review> mReviews=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Trailer> mTrailers=new ArrayList<>();

    public static final String MOVIE_REVIEWS_ARRAY ="movie_details";
    private static final String MOVIE_TRAILERS_ARRAY = "movie_reviews";
    private Typeface fontBold;
    private Typeface fontMediumLight;
    private Typeface fontMedium;

    private RecyclerView mReviewRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView mTrailerRecyclerView;

    private ProgressBar mReviewsProgressbar;
    private ProgressBar mTrailersProgressbar;
    private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinatorLayout;
    private CardView mReviewsCardView;
    private FloatingActionButton mFloatingActionButton;

    private ReviewsAdapter mReviewAdapter;
    private int NumOfReviews;
    private TrailersAdapter mTrailerAdapter;

    private String id;
    private boolean isFav;
    public DetailsFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Saving state in onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_REVIEWS_ARRAY,mReviews);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_TRAILERS_ARRAY,mTrailers);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);


        mBackdrop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.details_poster);

        mDetailTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_title_text);
        mReleaseDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.release_date);
        mOverview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.overview);
        mOverviewHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.overview_header);
        mReviesHeader=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.review_header);
        mTrailersHeader=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.trailer_header);

        mRatingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
        mCoordinatorLayout=(CoordinatorLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        mReviewRecyclerView= (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.review_recycler_view);
        mTrailerRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.trailer_recycler_view);

        mReviewsProgressbar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.reviews_progressbar);
        mTrailersProgressbar=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.trailers_progressbar);
        mFloatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mReviewsCardView= (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.reviews_card);


        intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        mMovie=bundle.getParcelable("PARCEL");
        tempMovie=mMovie;
        id = String.valueOf(mMovie.getMovieId());


        checkFav();
        mFloatingActionButton.show();

        assert mMovie != null;

        //PREPPING THE URL FOR QUERY

        String reviewQueryUrl = API.MOVIES_BASE_URL + id + "/reviews" + API.API_KEY;
        String trailerQueryUrl = API.MOVIES_BASE_URL + id + "/videos" + API.API_KEY;



        mDetailTitle.setText(mMovie.getTitle());
        mReleaseDate.setText(mMovie.getReleaseDate());
        mRatingBar.setProgress((int) mMovie.getVoteAverage());
        mOverview.setText(mMovie.getOverview());


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 21) {
            fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Bold.ttf");
            fontMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Medium.ttf");
            fontMediumLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Book_.ttf");


            mDetailTitle.setTypeface(fontBold);
            mReleaseDate.setTypeface(fontMedium);
            mOverview.setTypeface(fontMediumLight);
            mOverviewHeader.setTypeface(fontBold);
            mReviesHeader.setTypeface(fontBold);
            mTrailersHeader.setTypeface(fontBold);
        }



        //FETCHING JSON HERE
        if(savedInstanceState!=null&&savedInstanceState.containsKey(MOVIE_REVIEWS_ARRAY))
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"Restoring from bundle");
            mReviews=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_REVIEWS_ARRAY);
            mTrailers=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_TRAILERS_ARRAY);

            mReviewsProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTrailersProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        else {
            OkHttpHandler reviewsHandler = new OkHttpHandler(reviewQueryUrl, reviewsCallback);
            reviewsHandler.fetchData();

            OkHttpHandler trailersHandler= new OkHttpHandler(trailerQueryUrl, trailersCallback);
            trailersHandler.fetchData();

        }

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(API.IMAGE_URL + API.IMAGE_SIZE_500 + mMovie.getPosterPath())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(mBackdrop);
        getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition();





        mReviewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mReviewAdapter= new ReviewsAdapter();
        mReviewRecyclerView.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutmanager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        mTrailerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
        mTrailerAdapter= new TrailersAdapter();
        mTrailerRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTrailerAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private void checkFav() {
        movie=new ArrayList<>();
        movie=SugarRecord.find(Movie.class,"m_id=?",id);
        if(movie.size()==0)
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"Null");

            mFloatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
        }
        else {
            Log.v(TAG,"NOT Null");

            mFloatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
        }

        mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             movie=SugarRecord.find(Movie.class,"m_id=?",id);
                if(movie.size()>0)
                {
                    entry = movie.get(0);
                    entry.delete();
                    mFloatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,"Movie removed from Favourites!!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    View view= snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    entry = tempMovie;
                    entry.save();
                    mFloatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,"Movie added to Favourites!!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    View view= snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    snackbar.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }


    //OKHTTP CALLBACK FOR NETWORK CALL
    private okhttp3.Callback reviewsCallback = new okhttp3.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            //TODO handle failure on UI thread
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            try {
                String JSONData= response.body().string();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONData);
                NumOfReviews = jsonObject.getInt("total_results");
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                Log.v(TAG,JSONData);
                mReviews=parser.parseReviews(JSONData);



            } catch (JSONException e) {}

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(mReviewAdapter!=null)
                    {
                        mReviewsProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mReviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (NumOfReviews==0)
                    {
                        mReviewsCardView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private okhttp3.Callback trailersCallback = new okhttp3.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            //TODO handle failure on UI thread
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            try {
                String json1= response.body().string();
                JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
                Log.v(TAG, json1);
                mTrailers = parser.parseTrailers(json1);

            } catch (JSONException e) {}

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mTrailerAdapter!=null)
                    {
                        mTrailersProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mTrailerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private class ReviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView mAuthorText;
        private TextView mReviewText;
        private Review mReview;

        public ReviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mAuthorText= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_textview);
            mReviewText= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_textview);

        }

        public void bind(Review review)
        {
            mReview= review;

            mAuthorText.setText(mReview.getAuthor());
            mReviewText.setText(mReview.getContent());

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                mAuthorText.setTypeface(fontBold);
                mReviewText.setTypeface(fontMediumLight);
            }


        }
    }

    private class ReviewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReviewViewHolder>{

        @Override
        public ReviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.review_item,parent,false);
            return new ReviewViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ReviewViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Review review= mReviews.get(position);
            holder.bind(review);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if(mReviews==null)
            { return 0;}
            else
            {return mReviews.size();}
        }
    }

    private class TrailerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ImageView mTrailerThumbnail;
        private Trailer mTrailer;

        public TrailerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTrailerThumbnail=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.trailer_thumbnail);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bind(Trailer trailer)
        {
            mTrailer=trailer;

            Picasso picasso =Picasso.with(getActivity());
            picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            picasso.load(API.YOUTUBE_THUMBNAIL_URL+mTrailer.getKey()+API.THUMBNAIL_QUALITY)
                    .into(mTrailerThumbnail);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(API.YOUTUBE_TRAILER_URL+mTrailer.getKey()));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    private class TrailersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrailerViewHolder>
    {

        @Override
        public TrailerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.trailer_item,parent,false);
            return new TrailerViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(TrailerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Trailer trailer= mTrailers.get(position);
            holder.bind(trailer);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mTrailers.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Interface to communicate between Fragments ([Here's a question I asked an year ago and the accepted answer was really easy to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775691/passing-data-between-nested-fragments)).

Then, you need to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your callBack method.

Answer (score 1):

I propose one way to solve this.

```
class TabletActivity extends Activity implements DetailFragment.Callback {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         //Initialise fragments  

    }
    void onItemDelete(){
         // find the Master Fragment using FragmentManager;
         MasterFragment f = (MasterFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(); 
         if (f != null){
             f.somethingHasChanged();
         }
    }
}

class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private Callback callback;
    public onAttach(Context context){
         this.callback =  (Context) context;
    }
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle b){
         Button b;
         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
              public void onClick(View v){
                  callback.onItemDelete(); 
              }
         )
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onItemDelete();
    }


}
class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    public void somethingHasChanged(){
          adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
}
```

DetailFragment is where we initiate the changes, MasterFragment is consuming the changes. That communication is don't via the Activity. I personally don't recommend notifyAdapterChanges in OnResume() as you proposed because there is no guarantee that onResume will be call right after the changes in you data has been made.

Read more at:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks this looks easy to implement. I'll get back once I build it.