# Need to load or run a function in fragment 1 when I'm at fragment 2, update a table, then go to fragment 1

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments:

- Stock
- Sale
- Purchase

App starts with the Stock. It reads a table and based on the number of columns it creates `text views` and based on the number of rows it creates `linearlayouts`.

Sale updates the table by taking user inputs. So does the Purchase fragment.

The problem is when I make a sales entry or update the table, I don't see the changes in the Stock fragment, cause it is already loaded.

There's no problem with the Purchase fragment cause it is at position 3,so when I get back to Stock, it loads itself again and I can clearly see the changes.

**But have a problem with the Sale**, it is positioned at 2, which is middle, so can't see the changes occurred. To see them I have to go to no. 3 then go to 1.

How to load or just run a function which does the job for me in the Stock fragment, when I'm at position 2 n I swipe right to go to Stock????

It could be a duplicate question of a similar one, but I don't know cause couldn't figure out how to search for it.

Comment: Well some people love to downvote questions a lot. At least those people could give the reason for their actions.

Comment: @Sunil you suggested edits, couldn't you suggest an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface (listener). The sale fragment will notify the activity when the information is ready and the activity can pass on the data to the other 2 fragments.

You can look at the same question I asked a while back:

[Passing data between nested fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775691/passing-data-between-nested-fragments)

From what I read in your question, I believe a RecyclerView would be more suitable. SlideNerd, on Youtube, has a very easy to understand RecyclerViews and communication between Fragments. If you need more help, just ask :)

Comment: I have a function which makes `text views` and `linearlayout`and add them to the `linearlayout`. It does it by reading a table from the database. I run the function in the `onCreateView` which is in fragment 1 and when I update the table in fragment 2,  `onCreateView` doesn't run in fragment 1, so I don't c the `text views` updated. What you r suggesting can accomplish the task???

Comment: Yes. If done properly, it'll do exactly what you asked for in your question

Comment: Hi there, I know it's been a while since I expressed my interest in finding a solution. I was kinda busy but now back to work. I've learned about interface and implemented one. When I press the "add sale" button in "sale fragment", it runs a function that is in the host activity but now I just don't know how to run `onCreateView`method of "stock fragment"? I have a separate method in "stock fragment"  that creates "linearlayout and its children text views and set their texts". Don't wanna run it again cause it makes copies of them. HELP!!!!!